# Show the <div> after the loading of its child <div> from external PHP script is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, dynamic, loading

I am trying to create a dynamically generated chart in my PHP page. It works fine but I want to control the display such that the div containing the chart only shows after the chart finished loading.

HTML:

```
<div id="ViewsChartContainer">

   /* ... */            
      
   <div id="ViewsChart">
   </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#MyButton").on('click', function(){
   // hide the div
   $("#ViewsChartContainer").hide();

   // loading from PHP
   $('#ViewsChart').load(
      'UserStats/DrawLineChart.php', 
      {
         'project_id_arr': JSON.stringify(totalSelectedPrjIdArr), 
         'start_date': startDate,
         'end_date': endDate
      }
   ).fadeIn("slow");

   // show the div
   $("#ViewsChartContainer").show();
});
```

'UserStats/DrawLineChart.php' is just generating a canvas element, if you need I could provide the codes.

1. I have tried putting the JS code inside an async function and call `await`, but it is not doing anything.

   ```
   $("#MyButton").on('click', async function(){
      $("#ViewsChartContainer").hide();

      await $('#ViewsChart').load(
         /* ... */
      ).fadeIn('slow');

      $("#ViewsChartContainer").show();
   });
   ```
2. I cannot use `$(document).ready({})` because it is triggered on button click.
3. The only thing that's working is `setTimeout`

   ```
   $("#MyButton").on('click', function(){
      $("#ViewsChartContainer").hide();

      $('#ViewsChart').load(
         /* ... */
      ).fadeIn("slow");

      setTimeout(() => {
         $("#ViewsChartContainer").show();
      }, 2000);
   });
   ```

But it is hardcoded timing so I can't help thinking if there is a better way to do it. Kindly let me know if this is the only way to achieve this effect as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load()` comes with a callback. So you can change your code to the following and it should work.

```js
$("#MyButton").on('click', function(){
   $("#ViewsChartContainer").hide();

   $('#ViewsChart').load(
      /* ... */
   , () => {
       $("#ViewsChartContainer").show();
   }).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/load/

I believe when you were thinking of using `async` you were assuming it was using a promise. It is not, so `async` will have no effect. Before promises became a thing, the standard practice was to use callbacks (functions that are triggered when the operation is complete). Here is an article that gives some more information: [here](https://itnext.io/javascript-promises-vs-rxjs-observables-de5309583ca2#:%7E:text=The%20main%20difference%20between%20callbacks,do%20when%20the%20asynchronous%20task).

Answer (score -1):

You have a double-quote and then a single-quote when you select element for eventListener:

```
   // This 
$("#MyButton").on('click', function(){
   // hide the div
   $("#ViewsChartContainer").hide();

   // loading from PHP
   $('#ViewsChart').load(
      'UserStats/DrawLineChart.php', 
      {
         'project_id_arr': JSON.stringify(totalSelectedPrjIdArr), 
         'start_date': startDate,
         'end_date': endDate
      }
   ).fadeIn("slow");

   // show the div
   $("#ViewsChartContainer").show();
});
```

Comment: Ah right thank you for pointing it out! Was typing the button onclick function here instead of copying and pasting, thus the typo. But in my codes I believed I selected the elements correctly. I will edit. Thanks! @codeR developR

Comment: Strings can be defined using single and double quotes in JavaScript

Comment: I know... But the OP had starting double-quote and then an ending single-quote